# Custom icon fontface not showing on my website but showing for others?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My custom icon fontface is not showing on my website. I've spent a good amount of time searching for plausible causes for this, ranging from Browser Settings to Unicode range. Basically, I've followed the tutorial from over here:
http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ResponsiveIconGrid/

I successfully implemented it on my website. The functionality, the styles - everything is in check. Except that in place of the icons, I see rectangles/squares, which is frustrating to say the least.

I am using the exact same browser to view both websites and I can see the icons on codrops just fine. Do you guys/girls have any hints on what might be the issue?

I have added the fonts to my CSS; here it is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'anyoldicon';
    src:url('assets/anyoldicon.eot');
    src:url('assets/anyoldicon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('assets/anyoldicon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('assets/anyoldicon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('assets/anyoldicon.svg#anyoldicon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    unicode-range: U+00-FFFF;
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="cbp-ig-icon cbp-ig-icon-whippy"></span>
    <h3 class="cbp-ig-title">George</h3>
    <span class="cbp-ig-category">Smith</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Anything else I might have missed? I'd rather not show the URL, as it will teach you nothing more, to be honest. Its just as described - same layout, but visible on one website and broken on the other.

Here is the CSS corresponding to the icons and the animations of the grid: 
http://pastebin.com/94UgpN8B I also should mention that this icon font is generated by IcoMoon, if that is any help.

Lastly, I am using Muse to compile the website. I don't see how that would have a negative effect though. Could it be that somehow Muse is tinkering with the fonts?

Comment: Have you included the icon fonts in your css? I guess what I'm saying is... show us your CSS.

Comment: show us the HTML too, while you're at it.  What's your URL?

Comment: your icon is in a span so i assume it is a background image or setting content with css, show us the css related to the icon

Comment: Do you see any errors (maybe a 404) in console regarding your assets?

Comment: @brbcoding - I've updated with the info you guys asked me about. Thanks again.

Comment: Squares being displayed usually indicates that you did not link to the font source correctly, or the font files are missing.

Comment: The URL is really the only way to see the problem in context. Then we can see whether the font actually loads, what the font file contains, and whether the font is properly references in the CSS code. Besides, the CSS code posted does not show any attempt at actually *using* the font, and it seems that the font is based on some trickery (as “icon fonts” often are).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I believe your problem lies here:

**EDIT:** Hopefully more clear instructions.

Your `.cbp-ig-icon` class is probably not correctly being inherited by your additional classes that define the content. There might be something going on with the double `:before`. As a test, directly define the content under `.cbp-ig-icon:before` (font-family, etc), directly to your .cbp-ig-icon-show:before, and see if that works.

```
.cbp-ig-icon:before {
  font-family: 'anyoldicon';
  ...
}

.cbp-ig-icon-shoe:before { /** This is a totally separate class **/
  content: "\e000";
}
```

Comment: OK, I tried defining the styles under .cbp-ig-icon:before directly, but still no use.